# Detecting part of string and using part of it in a variable

Tags: c#

I have a TCP server setup that receives strings of text from clients.

```
data = new byte[1024];
recv = client.Receive(data);
string recvconv = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
```

I can detect a string and do something like this for example:

```
if (recvconv == "l")
{
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
    Console.WriteLine("l was printed...");
}
```

However I need to detect only part of a string. For example, "name:programmer". I need to be able to detect the "name:" part, AND then assign the "programmer" part of the string to a variable.

I am not sure how to do this. I have tried using substring, and other string techniques but I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Take a look at [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Behind the power of `String.SubString` and `String.Split`.

Comment: Paste some example string so we can prepare proper solution for You.

Comment: You could use RegEx and capture the value

Comment: some example strings would include: "name:john", "name:steven", "name:helloworld".

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Split method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
data = new byte[1024];
recv = client.Receive(data);
string recvconv = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

string[] results = recvconv.Split(':');
foreach (string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.StartsWith()` to detect the name at the beginning of the string, if you know that is where it will always be when you receive.

Use `String.Split()` if there is a known delimeter.  `String.Split()` will break the string into an array.  Take each element of the array an assign them to your local variables

```
data = new byte[1024];
recv = client.Receive(data);
string recvconv = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

string name = String.Empty;
string programmer = String.Empty;
if (recvconv.StartsWith("name"))
{
    string[] results = recvconv.Split(':');
    name = results[0];
    programmer = results[1];
}

// Do what you need to do with name & programmer
```

### Update

If I'm understanding your comment, you want to be able to selectively assign your received data to different variables.

So if the data, you intend to receive, is in the following format:

```
identifier:value
```

Where `identifier` is "name", "date", or any other field name that you may be expecting, and `value` is the value for that field, then you are better off just doing a `String.Split()` on the received data.  The first element of the array if what you would perform the `switch/case` evaluation.

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int recv = client.Receive(data);
string recvconv = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

string[] dataPieces = recvconv.Split(':');
switch (dataPieces[0])
{
    case "name":
        // Do what you need to do
        break;
    case "date":
        // Do what you need to do
        break;
    // Add more case/breaks if necessary
    default:
        // Possible error
        break;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to turn this if statement into a switch case statement for use with multiple values of "name", such as "date", or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find pattern is using the .net library to work with pattern.

```
string recvconv = "hello name:alex bye";
var math = Regex.Match(recvconv, @" name:[a-zA-Z]+");  // here you define the pattern to match.
if (math.Success)  // pattern matched
{
     var programmer = math.Groups[0].Value.Substring("name:".Length + 1);  // select the first pattern and take the name value.
}
```

Regex give you the posibility to define patterns as regular expressions, for example:

```
@"^name:[a-zA-Z]+"  // math with the pattern only if it is at the begin
@"name:[a-zA-Z]+"  // the pattern dosen't need to have a space before, for example: "holaname:alex" matched
@" name:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"  // if the name can contains numbers or underscore
...
```